# How to change the color of lightning-progress-indicator for type="path"

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-progressindicator

I want to have a custom color of the `lightning-progress-indicator` for the type="path" for all the type of stages i.e. complete , current and incomplete. I tried `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete` and `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathCompleteHover` and it worked completely fine, but when I use other property `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathCurrent` or `--lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncomplete` they doesn't seems to work as expected. I also try to add `!important` after the property value but no result. Please tell me where I went wrong!

**HTML**

```
<lightning-progress-indicator type="path" current-step="2" class="custom_css">
        <lightning-progress-step label="Step 1" onclick={launchFlow} value="1"></lightning-progress-step>
        <lightning-progress-step label="Step 2" onclick={launchFlow} value="2"></lightning-progress-step>
        <lightning-progress-step label="Step 3" onclick={launchFlow} value="3"></lightning-progress-step>
        <lightning-progress-step label="Step 4" onclick={launchFlow} value="4"></lightning-progress-step>
    </lightning-progress-indicator>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom_css {
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCurrent: rgb(221, 0, 255)!important;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete: #5a1ba9;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCompleteHover: #7526e3;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathCurrentHover: #05020e;
    --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncomplete: #ffff2d !important;
}
```

PS: Color value mentioned in the code is just for demo purpose, not the actual requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with `!important` you cannot override default style due to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-dom.html) encapsulation:

> Encapsulating the DOM gives developers the ability to share a component and protect the component from being manipulated by arbitrary HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
> [...]
> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child

Usually SLDS provides [Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-css-custom-properties.html) to customize component styling, but no one is listed for [Path](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/)nor for [Progress Indicator](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator/).
Moreover the CSS custom properties you listed are not defined in SLDS [Design Tokens](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/) so they shouldn't work.

Currenlty (Summer '23) you can only change `slds-is-incomplete` background color via styling hooks, i.e.

```css
.custom_css {
    --slds-g-color-neutral-base-80: #ff0000; /* incomplete:hover */
    --slds-g-color-neutral-base-95: #ffff2d; /* incomplete */
}
```

Therefore, if you need to fully customize a path component, you could build your own component starting from [blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it really helped me, but how do I find same styling hooks for the current stage?

Comment: @StackExchange you could [download the current Lightning Design System files](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/) and search for `.slds-path__nav .slds-is-complete`, `.slds-path__nav .slds-is-active` and `.slds-path__nav .slds-is-incomplete` in order to know which properties can be setted via styling hooks and the related tokens. You'll see that both `.slds-is-complete` and  `.slds-is-active` define a static value for `background`, while `.slds-is-incomplete` uses `background:var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-95, #f3f3f3);`